# Social networking SHARE feature in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, social-networking

I want to know how can we implement SHARE YOUR APP via facebook,twitter,linkedin features in a blackberry app..I have seen this implemented in Times Of India Blackberry app. Can anyone suggest what is the best way to implement this or has anyone implemented it?? I know for facebook we need to implement facebook SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter and LinkedIn got api's you can use too.

[Twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/)

[LinkedIn api](http://developer.linkedin.com/)